# Swift: unable to set background image

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried 2 different methods to set the background image-

first I tried setting it through the storyboard by creating an ImageView and setting the image to the image in my assets folder that way. I succeeded however the image was on top of the rest of the objects in my game and therefore was all I could see. I tried to send it to back using `Arrange`, but all the options under `Arrange` were unclickable (they were gray).

Next I tried setting it manually using this code:

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
yourview.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named:imageName))
```

Swift threw some errors and I had to add a few `!`s before it ran without the errors, but this did absolutely nothing.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I set the background image?

Comment: try making it a node instead

Comment: Is the view a UIView or a SpriteView? If you're setting the image on a UIView with a SpriteView on top the SpriteView will hide all content of the UIView because it is opaque.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the best solution for background image but I think its the simplest.

I set a background image in a UIView like this:

```
view.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "Something.png").CGImage
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly it's not working, but first off, I think the ".png" does not need to be added in your string:

```
    let imageName = "yourImage"
```

not:

```
    let imageName = "yourImage.png"
```

To do it in the storyboard you will have to first add the image to xcassets, then you add an image view to the story board (make sure it pans the whole size since it's meant to be a background. Then click the little square like button with a black line in it. This will pull up another tab, make sure that your image is higher up than any buttons, textfields, labels ect. (REMEMBER TO CONSTRAIN IT!)

Comment: yeah I didn't include .png

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the ViewDidLoad

> self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "YourImageName.png")!)

This works for me everytime...!! and drag and drop your image( YourImageName.png )in your supporting file folder and click copy if asked..!!

and if you want the background in every view controller then put this code in each view controller's ViewDidLoad()..!!